# release returned object or do i have to use autorelease

Tags: objective-c, release, autorelease, retaincount

sample code:

```
- (Foo*)createFoo {
    Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
    return foo;
}

- (void)someOtherMethod {
    Foo *foo;
    foo = [self createFoo]; //retain count 1
    [foo release]; //retain count = 0 => object gets released?

    //repeat
    foo = [self createFoo];
    [foo release];
}
```

Question: Do i have to autorelease in createFoo or can i release the returned object in someOtherMethod?

Comment: I suppose you are calling [self createFoo] and not [self Foo], then is ok to release it in someOtherMethod. Just keep in mind ARC let you get rid of almost all thess problems...

Comment: @ilMalvagioDottorProsciutto Whilst I agree on the ARC comment I think it is good to have a knowledge of how it should be done manually, besides ARC simply puts these calls in anyway, so knowing what it is doing is quite nice.

Comment: @SimonLee exactly my thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in this instance should be autoreleasing your object as you are handing over ownership to the calling code, you no longer wish to be responsible for it within the method and so you should relinquish your retain on it.

Remember NARC - methods that begin with these keywords are assumed to NOT autorelease...

New, Alloc, Retain, Copy

If your method were named `newFoo` or `copyFoo` then your code above would be fine without autoreleasing.

Comment: so nothing will go wrong and if rename createFoo to newFoo im following apples code requirements?

Comment: Yes that's fine, otherwise autorelease and then retain it in the calling code, and release when done.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa memory management is actually quite easy because everybody sticks to a set of rules.  You aren't following those rules, so you're going to run into trouble.

Read [Basic Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1).  If you stick to following those rules, you should be fine.